# Equation summary

Tags: equations

I am writing a book for my students and I wish, at the end of each chapter, do a summary of all important equations from that chapter (with its equation number, actual formula, and a little explanation about it -- somewhat like "Clapeyron Ideal Gas Equation").

Is there some easy manner of do that. Or I will need to be crazy with labels, copy-pasting, and so on?

Comment: Do you want the summary to restate the important equations?  Do you want the restated equations numbered?  Do you want them with the same numbers as they appeared earlier in the chapter?

Comment: Yes to all, if possible and with no much effort,

Comment: \savebox is an easy way to output the same thing twice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I introduce `\retaineqn{...}` to present but save an equation for later recapitulation, and `\recalleqn` to recall the next equation that had been previously saved (recapitulation phase).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcounter{retained}\setcounter{retained}{0}
\newcounter{shown}\setcounter{shown}{0}
\newcounter{saveequation}
\newcommand\retaineqn[1]{%
  \addtocounter{retained}{1}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname defeqnum\roman{retained}\endcsname{%
                                                 \arabic{equation}}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname defeq\roman{retained}\endcsname{#1}%
  \csname defeq\roman{retained}\endcsname%
}
\newcommand\recalleqn{%
  \addtocounter{shown}{1}%
  \setcounter{saveequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\csname defeqnum\roman{shown}\endcsname}%
  \csname defeq\roman{shown}\endcsname%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{saveequation}}%
}
\begin{document}

\section{A Chapter}

In equation~\ref{eq:first}, we present and retain an important equation.
\retaineqn{%
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:first}
y = x
\end{equation}
}%
Then we use it in a not so important equation~\ref{eq:second}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:second}
y = x^2
\end{equation}

Now for this next equation (equation~\ref{eq:third}), it is also important,
so we will retain it
\retaineqn{%
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:third}
y = x^3
\end{equation}
}%
 and use it to prove this last unimportant equation

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:fourth}
y = x^4
\end{equation}

\subsection{Recapitulation}

Our first retained equation was

\recalleqn

Our next retained equation was

\recalleqn

\section{Next Section}

Did equation numbers pick up in the right place?

\begin{equation}
 y = x^5
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant! A futher-more question: if there are certain subequations in the specific chapter, will `\recalleqn` work in right way?

Comment: @Ch'enMeng I doubt it will work, without extra twiddling, though it is possible.  But I don't use subequations to know for sure.  But you might try it to see.  And while you are throwing around adjectives like "brilliant", you might also find the time to throw a vote my way 8^O

Comment: Sorry I forgot it.:) Sadly, TeX reported an error for subequation from `amsmath`.

Comment: @Ch'enMeng Sorry to hear that subequations didn't work with the unaltered method.  I'm guessing that somehow there must be a subequation counter that needs tracking and storing, in the way that I did with `\csname defeq\roman{retained}\endcsname`

Comment: Hmmm, I think this approach is very good, but still need someone to complete it. I've got the way you tracking and storing equations and their count-numbers, which is the most important thing. :)

Comment: It is exactly what I was searching for. And, as asked, without much effort. You deserve more than one vote for that ;)

Comment: If I may add a suggestion, I do not know how complicated to create such implementation is, but perhaps combine \recalleqn with a label.

For example, I create an equation with the \label{eq:1}. Later I can recall it with \recalleqn{eq:1}.

Comment: @FabianoFagundes It is doable, but indeed more complicated.  If I have a chance, I may tackle it.  If successful, I'll repost.

Comment: Could I use this to recall ALL equations? Something like a cheat sheet of equations? I'd like this in such a way that I use one command (something like `\cheatsheet` ) on the end of my file so I have a one or two page cheatsheet of all formulas ( if possible even with a reference back to the original page).

Comment: @Snicksie Merry Christmas!  I think the approach could be used, but of course there is a lot of extra verbiage to be typed.  If I were to want to do this for *every* equation, I would try to build the retain feature directly into the equation environment, and I would also make it so I wouldn't have to recall each equation individually, but rather en masse.  There might already exist a package for this, if you don't have to selectively recall particular equations.